# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "A"

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    class B {
        typedef int INT;
        INT func(double e) {
            return INT(e * 3.6);
        }
    };
};
```

My problem is to remove the definition of `func` function from class declaration. This is the simplified case of my program. The compiler complains of typedef.

Here is my try:

```
template <typename T>
A<T>::B::INT A<T>::B::func(double e) {
    return INT(e * 3.6);
}
```

The compiler error is  `main.cpp:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "A".`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

g++ 4.7 pointed to the problem directly:

```
$ g++ 3.cpp
3.cpp:12:1: error: need 'typename' before 'A<T>::B::INT' because 'A<T>::B' is a dependent scope
```

So:

```
    template <typename T>
    typename A<T>::B::INT A<T>::B::func(double e) {
//  ^^^^^^^^
        return INT(e * 3.6);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
`main.cpp:14: error: redefinition of `typename A<T>::B::INT A<T>::B::func(double)'
main.cpp:6: error: `int A<T>::B::func(double)' previously declared here`

Comment: @Ashot: You are getting it because you forgot to remove the in-class definition. You can only have one. Make up your mind which one you want to keep: in-class or out-of-class one.

Comment: MSVC also gives a sensible error: "'A<T>::B::INT' : dependent name is not a type; prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type"